# How to differentiate between notes in note taking Android app?

Tags: java, android

The basic problem is that, in my note taking app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48EB4HeP1kI&list=LLhpPM8FLd5uST7RfQa_riQg&index=3&t=0s), creating a new note creates the same saved notes as the ones prior.

I modified the code so that the note format stored would not be one big edit `Text` but a table of values.

```java
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TableNoteEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("noteId", i);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

This is in the other `NoteEditorClass` with the table

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
        noteId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);

        if(noteId != -1){

            editText.setText(MainActivity.notes.get(noteId));

        } else {

            MainActivity.notes.add("");
            noteId = MainActivity.notes.size() - 1;
            MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                MainActivity.notes.set(noteId, String.valueOf(charSequence));
                MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.NoteLab", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(MainActivity.notes);

                sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I think `noteId` has something to do with differentiating between different notes. Sorry for being so clueless; I have only learned the basics of java in my Comp Sci course. Thanks in advance!